# Why won't Ubuntu boot with a series 5 ATI along with the Series 6 AMD's?

Tags: ati, 64-bit, xubuntu

My setup is as follows:

2 AMD Radeon HD 6900 Series 
 and a ATI Radeon HD 5670

Xubuntu 12.04 64bit and in case it makes a difference my Motherboard is a ASUS Formula IV. The driver versions I have tried are the stable and beta off the [downloads page for AMD graphics](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English), 13.1 and 13.2 Beta, would a old version help?

If I remove the ATI Radeon HD 5670 then the system boots up fine and I can bitcoin mine for hours but if I add the extra card the system boots but X server is never loaded, graphically the loading screen just hangs but the system can be accessed over SSH.